# Creating a for loop to find mean for a specific section of list

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to loop a list to find the mean for a specific window.
What I mean by this is for example:

```
num_list=[1,2,3,4,5]
window=3
```

Thus, I would find the mean for [1,2,3] , [2,3,4] and [3,4,5].
How I approached this was as the following:

```
average_list=[]
first_list=num_list[0:window]
def mean(data):
 n=len(data)
 mean=sum(data)/n
 return mean
for i in first_list:
 first_value=mean(i)
 average_list.append(first_value)
```

I am not quite sure how to incorporate the other two lists without typing it individually. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to iterate `num_list` taking slices of length `window`.

Try this:

```
mean_lst = [sum(num_list[i:i+window])/window for i in range(len(num_list)-window + 1)]
```

Result is

```
[2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the most obvious solution to your problem:

```
for i in range(list_len-window+1):
    average_list.append(mean(num_list[i:i+window]))
```

It does work properly, but it isn't optimal. Consider `num_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` and `window = 5`. Using obvious method, the code will first calculate the sum of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, then divide by `5`, then it will calculate the sum of `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, then divide by 5, and so on.

This code is clearly doing a lot more calculations than it needs to. An optimal way would be to calculate the mean of first window and then for calculating mean of every consecutive window remove the `first_element_of_previous_window/window_size` (`1/5` for 2nd window) and add `last_element_of_current_window/window_size` (`6/5` for 2nd window) to the mean of previous window. This approach avoids a lot of unnecessary calculations.

**Code Implementation**:

```
prev_mean = mean(num_list[:window])
average_list = [prev_mean]
for i in range(1, list_len-window+1):
    prev_mean -= num_list[i-1] / window
    prev_mean += num_list[i+window-1] / window
    average_list.append(prev_mean)
```